# Recursive merge sort in MIPS using stack

Tags: assembly, recursion, mips, mergesort

I am trying to implement the **merge sort** algorithm in a very dirty manner since it was told by our teacher to do so.

This program takes the input integer array from the user and prints the value of the array each time the sort is call (just for testing. I will correct it later). It is entirely dependent on stack . I was told to first implement it this way and then improve the algorithm further.

But, every time I am getting 0 as the output instead of the inputed numbers. To test I have run the code with 4 numbers (as input) as presented below

```
    .data    
Array1 :    .word 0:20

Array2 :        .word 0:20

    .text
    .globl main

main :


#initial activation record ... send the three arguments to sort......0
li $v0, 5           # system call for read_int
syscall
move $t4, $v0           # number read is put in $t0

li $v0, 5           # system call for read_int
syscall
move $t5, $v0           # number read is put in $t1

li $v0, 5           # system call for read_int
syscall
move $t6, $v0           # number read is put in $t2

li $v0, 5           # system call for read_int
syscall
move $t7, $v0           # number read is put in $t3

#do the syscall for array 1 and array 2(empty)(no syscall) and size save them in t0 , t1 , t2 respectively which are then send to stack

la $t0 , Array1
sw $t4 , 0($t0)
sw $t5 , 4($t0)
sw $t6 , 8($t0)
sw $t7 , 12($t0)

la $t1 , Array2
li $t2 , 4
sw $t0, -12($sp)
sw $t1, -8($sp)
sw $t2, -4($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, -184
jal sort


#.........display the result stored in B and then clear the stack (exit the program) ...........#

li $v0, 10          # system call for exit
syscall
#....................................................................0



#creating the initial activation record .............1 
sort:
# a0 mein A (initial one) and a1 mein B (initial one) a2 mein initial n which will be taken as system call
sw $ra, 168($sp)

#//already done addi $sp , $sp , -184


#for n1 and n2
lw  $t2 , 180($sp)              #($t2 = n)
srl $t0 , $t2 , 1           #($t0 = n1 = n/2)
sra $t0 , $t2 , 1   
sub $t1 , $t2 , $t0         #($t1 = n2 = n - n1)
sw $t1 , 164($sp)       #(stored n2)
sw $t0 , 160($sp)           #(stored n1)
#la $t0 , Array1            
#la $t1 , Array2    
#sw $t1 , 80($sp)       #stored ARRAY2
#sw $t0 , 0($sp)        #stored ARRAY1
#....................................................1

#SORT FUNC FIRST PART................................2

#ASSUMPTIONS:
#a0 = A
#a1 = B
#a2 = n




#BASE CASE
li $t0 , 1          #t0 = 1
bne $t0 , $t2 , firstL      #((t2 = n) != 1) then go to firstL
lw $t1 , 172($sp)           #t1 = &A
lw $t1 , 0($t1)         #t1 = A[0]
lw $t2 , 176($sp)       #t2 = &B
sw $t1 , 0($t2)         #B[0] = A[0]
#sw $t2 , 176($sp)      #stored &B at the desired position in stack
jr $ra

#First Loop

firstL :
#........................................................2

#CALLING SORT ...........................................3
lw $t8, 172($sp)            #loading &A
sw $t8, -12($sp)            #storing &A at the desired location
add $t8, $sp, $zero         #loading &A1
sw $t8, -8($sp)             #storing &A1 at the desired location
lw $t8, 160($sp)            #loading n1
sw $t8, -4($sp)             #storing n1 at the desired location
addi $sp, $sp, -184         
jal sort          


#.........................................................3

#CALLING SORT AGAIN ......................................4
lw $t8, 172($sp)            #loading &A
lw $t7, 160($sp)            #loading n1
sll $t7 , $t7 , 2           #n1*= 4 for mips address
add $t8 , $t8 , $t7             #adding &A + n1
sw $t8, -12($sp)            #storing &A + n1
addi $t8, $sp, 80           #loading &A2
sw $t8, -8($sp)             #storing A2
lw $t8, 164($sp)            #loading n2
sw $t8, -4($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, -184
jal sort

#calling merge...........................................5

add $a0, $sp, $zero     #a0 = &A1
addi $a1, $sp, 80   #a1 = &A2
lw $a2, 176($sp)    #a2 = &B
lw $t8, 160($sp)    
sw $t8, -8($sp)     #stored p
lw $t8, 164($sp)
sw $t8, -4($sp)     #stored q
addi $sp, $sp, -12
jal merge
#........................................................5

#return from sort........................................8
lw $ra, 168($sp)
lw $t0 , 176($sp)
lw $t1 , 0($t0)
lw $t2 , 4($t0)
lw $t3 , 8($t0)
lw $t4 , 12($t0)
li $v0, 1           # system call for print_int
    move $a0, $t1       # number in $t3 is to be printed
    syscall

li $v0, 1           # system call for print_int
    move $a0, $t2       # number in $t3 is to be printed
    syscall
li $v0, 1           # system call for print_int
    move $a0, $t3       # number in $t3 is to be printed
    syscall
li $v0, 1           # system call for print_int
    move $a0, $t4       # number in $t3 is to be printed
    syscall
addi $sp , $sp , 184

jr $ra
#........................................................8


#Merge ..................................................6

merge: 

sw $ra, 0($sp)      #stored ra              .........
#ASSUMPTION :
#a0 = P         #available from stack though.....
#a1 = Q
#a2 = R
#s1 = p
#s2 = q

lw $s1 , 4($sp)
lw $s2 , 8($sp)

move $t0 , $zero    # t0 = i , t1 = j, t2 = k (= 0) 
move $t1 , $zero
move $t2 , $zero
While1:
sll $t3 , $t0 , 2
add $t3 , $t3 , $a0      #t3 = &P[i]
sll $t4 , $t1 , 2
add $t4 , $t4 , $a1      #t4 = &Q[j]
lw $t5 , 0($t3)      #t5 = P[i]
lw $t6 , 0($t4)      #t6 = Q[j]
sll $t7 , $t2 , 2
add $t7 , $t7 , $a2  #t7 = &R[k]  
bge $t0 , $s1 , While2
bge $t1 , $s2 , While2   # exit loop 1 if j>=q or i>=p
bge $t5 , $t6 , While12
sw $t5 , 0($t7)          #R[k] = P[i]
addi $t0 , $t0 , 1   #incremented i and k
addi $t2 , $t2 , 1
j While1
While12:
sw $t6 , 0($t7)          #R[K] = Q[j] 
addi $t1 , $t1 , 1   #incremented j and k
addi $t2 , $t2 , 1
j While1

While2:
bge $t0 , $s1 , While3   #exit loop if i >= p
sw $t5 , 0($t7)          #R[k] = P[i]
addi $t0 , $t0 , 1   #incremented i and k
addi $t2 , $t2 , 1
j While1

While3:
bge $t1 , $s2 , Exit    #exit loop if j>= q
sw $t6 , 0($t7)         #R[k] = Q[j]
addi $t1 , $t1 , 1  #incremented j and k    
addi $t2 , $t2 , 1
j While1

Exit : 
#.........................................................6

#return from merge........................................7
lw $ra, 0($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 12
jr $ra
#..........................................................7
    #....................... END ..................................#
```

Please tell me why it is not working. I have tried a lot.

I would highly appreciate the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was very difficult but I figured out what the mistake was.

In the BASE CASE section, I had to restore the stack at the original point.
This is so because before the return of sort  the value 184 is added to the stack each time. 
I forgot that base case is also one instance of sort procedure itself. 
So, the value 184 has to be added there too .

Corrected program (base case part only) :

```
li $t0 , 1                          #t0 = 1
bne $t0 , $t2 , firstL              #((t2 = n) != 1) then go to firstL
lw $t1 , 172($sp)                   #t1 = &A 
lw $t1 , 0($t1)                     #t1 = A[0]
lw $t2 , 176($sp)                   #t2 = &B
sw $t1 , 0($t2)                     #B[0] = A[0]
addi $sp , $sp , 184                #THE CORRECTION
jr $ra
```